# How can i get updated row count from Excel using Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

Initially i have used 4 rows of data and then i deleted the last two rows . The problem is, i am still getting 4 as the total no of rows . What should i do to get updated count .

```
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    Sheet firstSheet = (Sheet) workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    System.out.println("No of rows:"+firstSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
    Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

    try{

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row nextRow = iterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();                      

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

             if(!cell.getStringCellValue().isEmpty()){

                 switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                     writer.append(cell.getStringCellValue());                         
                     break;                   

             }
             }             
             }               
             }       
      }finally{
        inputStream.close();
        workbook.close();           
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();            

    }
```

Comment: go to Excel document, select deleted rows and clear contents. If you have anything input in cell it will be marked as used and will been included to physical number of rows/cells unless You cleared it.

Comment: @TarasShpulyar I have cleared the contents by selecting the deleted rows using clear contents option . But i am still getting the same no of rows .

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been cleared by deleting Entire row in the Excel .if you want to delete some data in the excel , please don't just clear contents in the cell instead delete the entire row .